# How would I run a simple container the triggers Prometheus to reload its config when the underlying ConfigMap changes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

While running Prometheus in Kubernetes, I'm pushing out new config via a `ConfigMap`. ConfigMaps are exposed as files in the container.

I would love Prometheus to automatically reload its configuration when the file changes.

Would something like this work?

```
inotifywait -q -m -e close_write /etc/prometheus/config.yml |
while read -r filename event; do
  curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/-/reload
done
```

Comment: I've updated my answer - I actually found it quite interesting to have a fully working solution which can be used by everyone. Would be cool to hear if that works for you too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edit: I took some time to get this fully to work)
this works with a small sidecar container. The configuration could look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    ....
    spec:
      containers:
        ... (your actual container config goes here) ...
      - name: refresh
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
        - /etc/prometheus/config.yml
        - http://localhost:9090/-/reload
        image: tolleiv/k8s-prometheus-reload
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/prometheus
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus
```

The actual check is done with this script where the observed file and the URL are passed as parameters:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
   inotifywait "$(readlink -f $1)"
   echo "[$(date +%s)] Trigger refresh"
   curl -sSL -X POST "$2" > /dev/null
done
```

Everything can be found in [this container on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tolleiv/k8s-prometheus-reload/)

Keeping a single `inotifywait` with the `-m` didn't work because of symlink juggling which is done by Kubernetes when the `ConfigMap` changes.

Comment: Wow that is a very complete answer! Unfortunately I am seeing it trigger about 100 reloads a second via the prometheus logs.

Comment: Maybe if it did an md5 comparison on the file before making the curl...

Comment: Strange ... would be nice to know once it works for you too

Comment: I stand corrected it actually does work. I can't reproduce my run away refresh mode. Thanks!

Comment: Container is gone now. Please post the Dockerfile contents here

Comment: Sorry - not sure why  I removed it - it will be back in a few minutes. The Dockerfile etc. is [here](https://github.com/tolleiv/docker-misc/tree/master/2017-prometheus-reload)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a `livenessProbe` command and just trigger a restart of the `Pod` when the configuration changed.

That could look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prometheus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: prometheus
        image: prom/prometheus:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /etc/prometheus
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - "test -z $(find /etc/prometheus -mmin -2)"
          initialDelaySeconds: 300
          periodSeconds: 10
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: prometheus
```

A drawback could be that this way you'd loose the data cached in memory, but it's straight forward and doesn't need a sidecar container.

Comment: your approach restart the container and I would like to reload the configuration without any restart