# How to update Prometheus config in k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, config, prometheus

I have running Prometheus in k8s. Could you please advice how can I change running config `prometheus.yaml` in cluster? I just want simply to change:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: my-exporter
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you provide `prometheus.yaml ` configuration file through a `ConfigMap`?

Comment: yes, tried this.  All pods shoud be reloaded after this ?  is this the correct way how to change config in Prometheus (in k8s) ?

Comment: you don't have to. any change in configMap will be updated automatically in the pod. It might take some time to propagate update. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically

Comment: it doesnt work automatically- no idea why :/ but do you have idea why the aerospike-exporter doesnt provide data about aerospike?  the metrics page is working, promtheus see this but there is only  aerospike_node_up - that is all, no other statistic

Comment: sorry. i am not familiar with aerospike. so i can't help.

Comment: maybe this is general question not just about aerospike.  The exporter try to get statistic from DB on loclahost:3000  and provide metrics on :9145 port for prometheus.  the pod with exporter has accees to localhost:3000 to get data ?

Comment: Exporter should be run as sidecar container of DB pod.  Then, the exporter will have access to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: ok, so i will create daemonset for exporters - this will run exporter on every nod right?  and all of them will try to get stats on localhost:3000 and report with succets it theres is running aerospike on port 3000.  i hope i uderstand it ;/

Comment: no. you have to run exporter as sidecar of aerospike pod. exporter and aerospike container must run on same pod. otherwise, exporter will not able access `localhost:3000`. can you show me how did you installed aerospike? There might be some other way to retrieve metrics.

Comment: i installed it via helm in kubernetes cluster (gcloud)

Comment: so i will run only one exporter in whole cluster? how can deoplot it to the same nod as aerospike ?

Comment: can you point me to the exporter you want to use?

Comment: this one, as docker container.  https://hub.docker.com/r/ysde/docker-aerospike-exporter/

Comment: looking at the exporter description and aerospike chart what i understand is that, when you are deploying aerospike in kubernetes, each pod of aerospike denotes a node of aerospike cluster. the exporter says, it has to run on every nodes of aerospike cluster. that means the exporter has to run in every aerospike pod. So, you have to run exporter image aerospike pod along with aerospike image. But the problem is, chart installation process does not have a way to add exporter image to the statefulset.

Comment: however, it seems that you can set  aerospike node address using `--node` flag. This means you can run exporter in a separate deployment and point it to collect metrics from aerospike pod.

Comment: so, i can deploy one exporter in whole cluster and point it to aerospike DB with --node ?  how will i address it ? with some ip?

Comment: I think so. Are you deploying exporter with a deployment? Then pass `--node="http://<areospike-service-name>.<namespace>.svc:3000` as `agrs` of exporter container.

Comment: maybe i still dont undertand how to deploy exporter to specific pod? with my application - so aerospike DB for example and not to other pods..

Comment: ok. then i should deploy a aerospike db first and try to use exporter. then i should instruct you how to do it.

Comment: yes, i have it.  Now, should i deploy aerospike exporter as daemonset to all nodes? or just deploy one  instance to cluster?

Comment: just install one instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I run a simple container the triggers Prometheus to reload its config when the underlying ConfigMap changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992258/how-would-i-run-a-simple-container-the-triggers-prometheus-to-reload-its-config)

Answer (score 13):

The recommended way is to provide the `prometheus.yml` via a ConfigMap. That way  changes in the ConfigMap will be propagated into the pod that consumes the configMap. However, that is not enough for prometheus to pick up the new config.

Prometheus supports [runtime reload of the config](https://www.robustperception.io/reloading-prometheus-configuration), so that you don't need to stop prometheus in order to pickup the new config. You can either do that manually by sending a POST request as described in the link above, or automate this process by having a sidecar container inside the same prometheus pod that watch for updates to the config file and does the reload POST request.

The following is an example on the second approach: [prometheus-configmaps-continuous-deployment](https://www.weave.works/blog/prometheus-configmaps-continuous-deployment/)

Comment: yes, it is working. i provided the config file via configmap. and aplly with kubectl -f

Comment: Could you provide the steps/commands necessary to add a new configmap to prometheus? I'm not sure how to proceed from just your description, sorry.

Comment: @dvdblk I've just done all the steps in prometheus k8s configuration installed using helm charts: alias k kubectl
1. `k get configmap prometheus-server -o yaml > cfg.yaml`
2. edit cfg.yaml
3. `k apply -f cfg.yaml` // this will renew files in prometheus-server:/etc/config/
4. `k port-forward prometheus-server-6b6c87ffc6-flgck 9090`
5. `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload`