# How to modify existing prometheus operator helm install?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, operator-keyword

I've installed Prometheus operator using helm and noticed that there is no PVC attached. I want to edit the installation to use a PVC to persist metrics. Per docs, I should do the following, however it's still unclear to me how/where I can set this? I've already created PVs on the node local disks, and a default storage class to use those.

Do I just `kubectl apply` that yaml? How? Why would that work?

Sorry for the basic question but just can't wrap my head around how to edit kubernetes operator configurations.

[Source](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/release-0.29/Documentation/user-guides/storage.md).

Comment: Could you provide more information (such as commands, yaml files) that you used? That will be helpful to reproduce your problem. Please, attach also version of Kubernetes that you used. According to the link you provided can I assume, that you're using AWS? How did you set up your cluster? By the time take a look also at [this](https://ystatit.medium.com/k8s-pv-pvc-and-configmap-for-prometheus-and-grafana-caa044b0d82b) and [this](https://medium.com/@kevincoakley/reusable-persistent-volumes-with-the-existingclaim-option-for-the-grafana-prometheus-operator-84568b96315) articles.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://www.robustperception.io/reloading-prometheus-configuration):

> A common question from new users is if they need to restart [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) every time they change the configuration. The good news is that you don't, allowing your monitoring to continue uninterrupted as your system changes.

You have two ways to pickup the new config in Prometheus.

First one is an manual method. You need to send `POST` request to the Prometheus web server:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9090/-/reload
```

Second one is automation this process ([example](https://www.weave.works/blog/prometheus-configmaps-continuous-deployment/)).
You need to have a sidecar in the same prometheus container that monitors config file's updates and reloads the `POST` request.

See also:

- [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227819/how-to-update-prometheus-config-in-k8s-cluster),
- [this documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#:%7E:text=Prometheus%20can%20reload%20its%20configuration,%2Dlifecycle%20flag%20is%20enabled) (here one can find whole configuration for Prometheus described).